# Как сделать div на iOS-устройствах кликабельным?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, вёрстка

Столкнулся с какой-то аномалией. Всем известно, что у iOS свои приколы с обработкой клика на мобильной платформе, но тут просто что-то невероятное.
Я написал несложное приложение и просто не понимаю почему не срабатывают клики на div элементах разметки.
Я попробовал:
- задать cursor: pointer (как в теге style, так и в самом div'е)

```
<style>
    .poi {
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: transform 0.1s ease;
      transform: scale(1);
      user-select: none;
    }
</style>
```

- задать tabIndex="1"

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" class="name" placeholder="Имя (Опционально)">
```

- задать onClick="" (пробовал и писать внутри параметра атрибута название соответствующей функции - не помогло)

```
<div tabindex="4" class="load poi" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick=""><span>Загрузить</span></div>
```

- использовать touchend вместо click или mouseup

```
const event = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)? "touchend" : "click";
calculateButton.addEventListener(event, () => {
    calculate();
});
```

Большинство решений было найдено здесь, но ничего из этого ни в отдельности ни в совокупности не помогло.
Проверка проводилась на iPhone XR iOS 13.4.1.
Весь код можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/fearistoff/MatrixOfLife), а посмотреть [здесь](https://fearistoff.github.io/MatrixOfLife/).
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: user-select: none; вот на это вот обработчики в ios плохо реагируют

Comment: Возможно, но user-select: none; назначен не на все кнопки, что есть в приложении. Или это не принципиально?

Comment: Не убрав эту опцию - не понять. Мне это помогало. Это свойство на мобильной версии даже вешало компонент реакта с input'ом. Я не знаю, что там за закономерность. Но, думаю, попробовать стоит.

Comment: @NeedHate везде убрал, не помогло...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте также завязаться на `touchstart`:

```
 document.addEventListener('touchstart', calculate);
```

У меня такое решение сработало.

Comment: Попробовал и добавить также в разметку и просто в код как вы сказали - не помогло... @Vadizar